# Intercept function call with mock without pytest/unittest/etc

Tags: python, dependency-injection, mocking

I want to avoid using a test runner such as pytest because of slow test discovery and inconvenient logging output in lieu of setting up my test and calling it as a script however I am having trouble intercepting a function call within my test objects and amending its behavior. I have been able to do this in the past with pytest but I can't seem to get access to the function the way I have things setup. Side note: In part, this is an attempt to mock out a call to a RESTful server which should explain why I am interested in getting this to work.

Here is my sample application structure:

```
# entry_object.py
import inner_object, time

class EntryObject(): 
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.inner_obj = inner_object.InnerObject(client)
        pass
    
    def time_injector(self, posix_time : int):
        self.inner_obj.doit(posix_time)
        pass


def the_time_injector(length_in_secs, client) -> None:
    entryobj = EntryObject(client)
    i = 0;
    posix_time = time.time()
    while (i < length_in_secs):
        entryobj.time_injector(posix_time+i)
        i += 1
```

```
# inner_object.py
import pretendapi

class InnerObject(): 
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.pretend_api_object = pretendapi.PretendApi(client)
        
    def doit(self, posix_time : int) -> None:
        logmessage = self.pretend_api_object.call_api_endpoint(posix_time=posix_time)
```

```
# pretendapi.py
import bravado

class PretendApi():
    def __init__(self, client=None):
        print("Created PretendApi")
        self.client =  bravado.client.SwaggerClient(None) if client is None else client
        self.ex = "pretendapi"


    def extract_and_verify_apiresult(self, posix_time : int, apiresult : object) -> (bool, object):
        return (True, apiresult[0])
    
    def call_api_endpoint(self, posix_time : int) -> object:
        future = self.client.Api.ApiEndpoint()
        (is_cmd_success, apiresult) = self.extract_and_verify_apiresult(posix_time, future.result())

        if not is_cmd_success:
            # print(f"is_cmd_success={dollup(is_cmd_success)}")
            return is_cmd_success

        # print(f"{apiresult}")
        return is_cmd_success
```

```
# test_entry_object.py
rom bravado.testing.response_mocks import BravadoResponseMock
import mock
import entry_object, pretendapi


def amend_extract_and_verify_apiresult(original_func):
    def amended_func(self, posix_time : int, apiresult : object) -> (bool, object):
        print(f"{posix_time} {apiresult[0]['ret_msg']}")
        return original_func(self, posix_time, object)

def test_time_injector():
    # mock the necessary objects
    # setup up the unit under test
    # run the test
    mock_client = mock.Mock(name='mock SwaggerClient')
    mock_client.Api.ApiEndpoint.return_value = \
        BravadoResponseMock(result=lambda : \
            ({'ret_code': 0, 'ret_msg': 'OK', 'ext_code': '', 'ext_info': ''}, '<bravado.requests_client.RequestsResponseAdapter object at 0x0000028385176518>')
            )
    mock.patch.object(pretendapi.PretendApi, 'extract_and_verify_apiresult',
                        side_effect=amend_extract_and_verify_apiresult(
                            pretendapi.PretendApi.extract_and_verify_apiresult),
                        autospec=True) # Needed for the self argument
    entry_object.the_time_injector(10, mock_client)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_time_injector()
```

Does anybody understand why I can't seem to decorate the behavior of `extract_and_verify_apiresult`?

Comment: Have you tried specifying you `testpaths` to pytest to speed up discovery?

Comment: I have, so it might not only be test discovery that slows things down.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long does discovery take for you? I find the discovery time unsubstantial to the time it actually takes to run the tests. Point being, maybe its worth to figure out why discovery is slow instead of writing a testing suite from scratch.

Comment: I haven't timed it in a while but I do recall it was somewhere between ~10 to ~20 seconds. I want to eventually pin down the root cause of the slow startup time. Slow discovery is not the only reason I am interested in this route and that is the debugger/test runner/logger combo. When I run code from script entry, I get logging real time with debugging but with pytest I have to define `log_cli = True` to get log output which is duplicated after test completion and also adds to the ungodly slow down. (SMH with ??? lol)

Comment: Alright, understood, I don't think I can help you with this specifically. As a final note, if you happen to be using VSCode, I would recommend checking out https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter I use it myself all the time to debug individual tests without having to call the whole testing stack, avoiding all the extra steps you seems to be frustrated with as well.

Comment: Well the intention is to test the entire stack to do end to end testing. Thank you for the suggestion though.